# Which is going to be the very last block of 2017?

Tags: blockchain, blocks, block-interval, timestamp, timers

I know that the last moment of the year depends in which time zone you are. But lets assume that we want the very last moment, so let's consider the last time zone (+12), I believe is Fiji or New Zealand.

[image]

Which is going to be the newest block in the ethereum blockchain at 11:59PM of December 31th 2017 in Fiji?

I know that it isn't that exact but is there a good approach of which block is going to be, considering there is a new block every 17 seconds aprox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment I'm writing this answer it is: 1072718 seconds to the end of the current year in the [timezone +12](https://www.timeanddate.com/counters/newyear.html?p0=264), [block number](https://etherscan.io/) 4757253 in Ethereum mainnet, so we will be at the block number 4820354 by the very end of this year.

*As avg I took 17 seconds as the author mentioned in his question, but etherscan says release frequency of the block is 14.76s Avg now.*